# Are fulltext (match against) queries with Propel2 possible?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, propel

With Propel2 and MySQL/InnoDB, I want to execute a fulltext query on the `VARCHAR` columns `title` and `director` of a table `movies`. In plain SQL this would read

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE
    MATCH(title, director) AGAINST("big lebowski" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

How can this query be constructed with the Propel2 framework?

---

#### Note on creating a FULLTEXT index in schema.xml

I succeeded in creating the `FULLTEXT` index with the Propel2 `schema.xml` file by including:

```
<index name="fulltext">
  <index-column name="title"/>
  <index-column name="director"/>
  <vendor type="mysql">
    <parameter name="Index_type" value="FULLTEXT"/>
  </vendor>
</index>
```

All that's missing is the query. :) Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$movies = MovieQuery::create()
    -> where('MATCH(Movie.title, Movie.director) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)',
             'big lebowski')
    -> find();
```

See the [Propel documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html#combining-several-conditions).